# Can I access the geometery of a the Sphere class without extending?

Tags: java, inheritance, geometry, java-3d, extends

I'm trying to create a generic abstract superclass for all 3d objects in a Java3D program I am writing. I need this to add shared functionality, such as moving objects, to all 3d objects via a common interface. I would like to use the pre-existing geometry of the Sphere class to create my own sphere3d object.

I want to be able to access the geometry of the Sphere class without inheriting it, as my object3d abstract class extends Shape3D and thus subclasses must inherit object3d. Is there a way to set the geometry of my own sphere3d class (which extends object3d) to that of Sphere? The geometry is all I need.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

```
float radius = 2.4f;
int divisions = 24;
// Further flags: GENERATE_TEXTURE_COORDS etc.
int primflags = Sphere.GEOMETRY_NOT_SHARED | Sphere.GENERATE_NORMALS;

Sphere sphere = new Sphere(radius, primflags, divisions);

Shape3D shape3D = sphere.getShape();

Geometry = shape3D.getGeometry(); // Your desired result !

shape3D.setGeometry(null);
```